# SQL: Is UNION the same as SELECT DISTINCT with UNION ALL subquery

Tags: sql, database

Are these two SQL statements identical in all scenarios?

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM tablename UNION ALL SELECT * FROM tablename2) dummyname
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM tablename UNION SELECT * FROM tablename2
```

The thing I always find peculiar about UNION is that it removes all non-distinct rows even if those non-distinct rows appear within a single part of the UNION clause. For example, lets say tablename has one column: amt INT. Let's say amt INT is NOT a primary key and does not have any unique constraint on it. Then let's say I have two rows where amt = 20. Regardless of the UNION that I do, only one of those two rows will appear in the resulting set.

I was explaining this behavior to someone else, and then came up with above examples to demonstrate the behavior of UNION... I believe those two statements above are the same (always), but I just want to make sure that what I said is correct. Are there any edge cases where the two SQL statements above will not generate a totally identical result set?

Comment: Here is a good article that will explain this clearly: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/11/sql-server-difference-between-union-vs-union-all-optimal-performance-comparison/

Comment: Yes they are the same, only remember to never use `*` within a union clause. Because you can get a column order hell.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I would go as far as to say never use [`SELECT *` at all in production code](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list).

Comment: I totally agree with you on that! Thanks for mention it. @GarethD

Comment: @JorgeCampos and GarethD Fair points and worth mentioning. What I wrote here was just rough SQL to illustrate the point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two versions are identical:  `UNION` is functionally equivalent to `SELECT DISTINCT` on the `UNION ALL`.

`UNION` removes duplicate values within a table as well as values shared between the two tables.

I should note that from a performance point of view, the following is often faster than just a `UNION`:

```
select distinct t.col1, t.col2
from t
union
select distinct t1.col1, t.col2
from t1;
```

This may be counterintuitive.  But, if there is an index on `(col1, col2)` in the tables, then it can be used for the `select distinct`, reducing the number of rows for the `union`.  Some optimizers might miss this opportunity to simplify the inputs.

Answer (score 2):

In short yes you can find the explanation [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/11/sql-server-difference-between-union-vs-union-all-optimal-performance-comparison/):

```
/* Declare First Table */
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (ColDetail VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @Table1
SELECT 'First'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Second'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Third'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fourth'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fifth'
/* Declare Second Table */
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (ColDetail VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @Table2
SELECT 'First'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Third'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fifth'

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (SELECT * FROM @Table1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM @Table2) dummyname
```

result 1:

[image]

```
SELECT * FROM @Table1 UNION SELECT * FROM @Table2
```

result 2:

[image]